# ASP.net Core API how to handle concurrency

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]
how to handle the concurrency update, example i have an api to perform task and return a sequential running number to clients. What happen is if all the client perform the request at the same time (let assume it really happen), some of the client wont get the correct running number. how to handle this, i am thinking using lock{ }, but it will cause performance issue. any suggestion?

Comment: Are you talking about updating some kind of database? If so, you have the optimistic concurrency pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control.

Comment: thank u, i have updated the code